# cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-gd-1_36.lib

Tags: boost, hyperlink

I dont have visual studio 2008 installed.I am using 2012 and i rebuild this projects by cleaning.I checked the project settings and controlled the additional libraries and unfortunately I couldnt find any lib link has this name...in project just .h files of date_time are used but no lib linking. I configured new version of boost but STILL it wants this lib ? so is there any way I can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio, boost use an auto linking system.

> Special code in Boost header files detects your compiler options and
>   uses that information to encode the name of the correct library into
>   your object files; the linker selects the library with that name from
>   the directories you've told it to search.

`date_time` is one of boost modules that need a library (which is not header only).

So, you have to build them, using bjam (and `--toolset=msvc-9.0)`, or retrieve them already built for your system.

Other option: disable auto linking. Just define

> BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB

And link manually.